# PHP Search and Query Results

Tags: php, search

Here is my issue. I have a database I want to search by name only. If there are similar names I want it to pop up and give an option to pick which one. Once you do and click search it goes into a search.php file... I want to display results but the GET method does not seem to work. 
Here is my form.

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="query" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Here is my PHP search

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
/*
    localhost - it's location of the mysql server, usually localhost
    root - your username
    third is your password

    if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
*/

mysql_select_db("ambassador") or die(mysql_error());
/* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */


$query = $_GET['query'];
// gets value sent over search form

$min_length = 3;
// you can set minimum length of the query if you want

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member
        WHERE (`Name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

        }

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Then I try to use this method to get results from database.

```
<?php echo $_GET['Name']; ?>
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Try to var_dump($_GET) at top of you code  to see what are you sending. and close the form tag

Comment: I put var_dump($_GET) at top of my code and it does nothing different. Form is closed

Comment: @X_JuDaH_X CHECK if you are redirected to the page you want,echo something in the beginning and see if it's shown

Comment: IS this the right way to search database in the first place? Or should I use results instead of GET. IF so how do I do that?

Comment: @FaceOfJock Yes it redirects me to search.php.  But it does not display my results of the search. Code I am using is <?php echo $_GET['Name']; ?> I also tried <?php echo $_REQUEST['Name']; ?>

Comment: replace your php page with <?php print_r($_GET);?> and show me what's the result

Comment: @FaceOfJock It came up with   Array ( [query] => test )   Test is name I searched for..

Comment: I tried your form and it work fro me. As @X_JuDaH_X CHECK if you've been redirected (301 redirect not by submit butten) then you form will not work correctly check you application for redirect.

Comment: @X_JuDaH_X that's ok , so your get is ok ,now test your query in database and test if it gives you results , also , try in php query without your Where clause and display all data, try to debug ,part by part until you know the problem

Comment: It is getting confusing to me now. Sorry.. Is there some code or place I can see a simple search by name in database and it will display results? Does not have to be with GET. Can be with results, or row or POST. I have been bale to get a form that works perfect and posts onto new page...But later when they go search name I cannot get output from the database. Info is in database. Juts the GET methods are not working. @FaceOfJock

Comment: Have you tried switching PHP notices on to see if there's a syntax error or something?

Comment: There are no errors. It just does not display results. Once I connect to database I want it to go off of name search we did and then display some of the tables from that name. @PatrickGeyer

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "password")  at this line , username is called dbname ? , it's not database name , it should be USERNAME there

Comment: @FaceOfJock  Yes I blocked it for posting it here...it connects to database great.

Comment: @X_JuDaH_X try the answer i gave you

Comment: @FaceOfJock This worked...It displayed all the database results from everything.. Now I just want to get results only from person I searched and display (only one person) and the results I choose.. Like name only with telephone and email. Not address.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer , i put code here because it's not well formated in the comment.
So , try this part of code ,it should display result according to the name in the form :

HTML:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "dbname", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("ambassador") or die(mysql_error());

    //check if variable $_POST['name'] has a value
    if(isset($_GET['name'])) $name=$_GET['name'];
    else $name="";

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member where name='".$name."'") or die(mysql_error());


            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

                echo $results['name'].'<br/>';
            }
     ?>
```

Comment: This worked...It displayed all the database results from everything.. Now I just want to get results only from person I searched and display (only one person) and the results I choose.. Like name only with telephone and email. Not address.

Comment: cool , now we will send a post variable that contains name of member and we will display all his informations , i will edit my answer

Comment: Actually it does bring up Name  but not other Get queries I want to get. @FaceOfJock

Comment: replace by this line and change example name by a naw in your database `$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member where name='example name'") or die(mysql_error());`
 ,has your table membre a field name ?

Comment: Where example name is I entered a name that is in database..Came up with results. The field name is Name , Yet I dont want it to display everything in the fields for that one name. @FaceOfJock

Comment: i added echo to show only the name , i will not code for you , i'm juste giving you help